# Filtering only address from USA with use-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

I'm using use-places-autocomplete fro getting results from the google api. On my hook I have the following configuration

```
usePlacesAutocomplete({
 requestOptions: {
   types: ["address"],
   componentRestrictions: {
     country: "us",
   },
 }
```

But when typing `Holly` I'm getting some results that don't have specific address as the one that are on the image, because they are cities.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong in this case? I want to get only the suggestions from USA with a specific address. Does the hook enabled this ?

Comment: Seems like they are using [requestOptionsRef](https://github.com/wellyshen/use-places-autocomplete/blob/master/src/usePlacesAutocomplete.ts#L136).
Maybe it's a cache issue on our side, try `sessionStorage.removeItem('upa');`

Comment: Thanks ! Finally I clean the cache with the method that comes on the hook and it works.